# Recursive bash function (directory iterator)

Tags: bash, unix, recursion

I know that my following task could be accomplished using simpler 'find' comment, but I am trying to implement a solution using a recursive call. I am looking through a specific directory and trying to get max length of any filename in all the sub-directories. However, my recursion works only one level down, so it basically returns me the longest filename in a certain directory or in its' subdirectories.

```
#! /bin/bash

export maxlen=0

findmaxr()
{
        if [ $# -eq  0 ] ; then
        echo "Please pass arguments. Usage: findmax dir"
        exit -1
        fi

        if [ ! -d "$1" ];       then
        echo "No such directory exist."
        exit -2
        fi

        for file in $(/bin/ls $1)
                do
                if [ -d "$file" ] ; then
                        findmaxr $file   # Recursively call the method for subdirectories
                else
                        cur=${#file}
                        if [ $maxlen -lt $cur ] ; then
                                maxlen=$cur
                        fi
                fi
                done

        echo "The file with the longest name has [$maxlen] characters."



}

findmaxr `pwd`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here. The biggest is that in `[ -d "$file" ]` and `findmaxr $file`, the `file` variable only contains the file's name, not the entire path. So, if you're in /dir, and /dir/sub/sub2 exists, the top level will run `findmaxr /dir` (which is fine), that will run `findmaxr sub` (which works, but isn't really what you want), which then runs `findmaxr sub2` (which doesn't work at all). So one possibility would be to use `"$1/$file"` in these lines, but there's another problem: [parsing `ls` is a bad idea and will fail for some directory names](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It'd be better to use `for path in "$1"/*`, which doesn't have parsing issues (provided you double-quote all variable references, which you should anyway) *and* gives you the full path so you don't have to prepend `$1/`. But then you have to strip the front of the path before checking the filename length, with something like `local file="$(basename "$path")"`.

The second problem is that it prints `$maxlen` after finishing with each directory, not just after the entire tree has been scanned. To fix this, just move that command out of the recursive function to the main sequence, after it runs `findmaxr`.

There's another subtler problem as well: `file` (`cur`, and `path` if you follow my recommendation) are not local variables, which means the recursive call can change their values un the calling instance of `findmaxr`. You should declare them as local variable to avoid confusion. Oh, and it's not necessary to export `maxlen` -- it'll automatically be global within the script, and it's not relevant to any of the commands you're running (which `export` passes it to).

Comment: Thank you. I read somewhere else that parsing ls is problematic, but could not find an explanation for that. The info you provided is very useful!

Answer (score 2):

each instance of findmaxr needs to return the maxlen it found (via echo), you need to include that output in your comparison.

there is another problem: assume `a`, `b`, and `c` are directories, `d.txt` is a file, and they are arranged like this: `a/b/c/d.txt`. run the script from inside `a`. when `file` is `b`, `if [ -d "$file" ]` is true, and `findmaxr b` gets called. it calls `ls b`, which in turn leads to `findmaxr c`, which leads to `ls c`... except `ls c` fails, because you're still in `a`. you need either to `cd` into subdirectories or else include the whole path, like this: `$1/$file`.

here is your script with those problems fixed:

```
#!/bin/bash

findmaxr()
{
    if [ $# -eq  0 ] ; then
    echo "Please pass arguments. Usage: findmax dir"
    exit -1
    fi

    if [ ! -d "$1" ];       then
    echo "No such directory exist."
    exit -2
    fi

    maxlen=0
    for file in $(/bin/ls "$1")
            do
            if [ -d "$1/$file" ] ; then
                    cur=`findmaxr "$1/$file"`   # Recursively call the method for subdirectories
            else
                    cur=${#file}
            fi
            if [ $maxlen -lt $cur ] ; then
                maxlen=$cur
            fi
        done
        echo $maxlen
}

maxlen=$(findmaxr $(pwd))
echo "The file with the longest name has [$maxlen] characters."
```